# How is it possible to apply the fundamental lemma of variations in mechanics?

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to understand the derivation of Timoshenko beam equation on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko_beam_theory#Quasistatic_Timoshenko_beam)

At one point we arrive at the following:

$$ \int_L \left[\left(\frac{\partial M_{xx}}{\partial x} - Q_x\right)~\delta\varphi - \left(\frac{\partial Q_{x}}{\partial x} + q\right)~\delta w\right]~\mathrm{d}L = 0 $$

where the integral is taken along the length $L$ of the beam. The moment $M_{xx}$, the shear force $Q_{x}$ and the variations on the beam angle and deflection, $\delta \varphi$ and $\delta w$, are functions of $x$.

Then:

> The governing equations for the beam are, from the fundamental theorem of variational calculus,

$$ \frac{\partial M_{xx}}{\partial x} - Q_x = 0 ~;~~ \frac{\partial Q_{x}}{\partial x} + q = 0 $$

I know the fundamental theorem/lemma of variational calculus is: If a smooth function $f(x)$ satisfies the following formula for **any** $h(x)$ with certain properties on the interval between $a$ and $b$, then $f(x)=0$.

$${\displaystyle \int _{a}^{b}f(x)h(x)\,\operatorname {d} x=0}$$

So, as I understand, the function $h(x)$ can be any arbitrary function on the interval as long as it vanishes outside the interval. The above identity has to hold for all such functions.

**But beam theory specifically assumes that deflections of the beam are small.** Functions $\delta \varphi$ and $\delta w$ therefore must be (infinitesimally) small along the beam. So how can we apply the fundamental lemma to he first equation if the lemma requires that $h(x)$ can be **any**, even arbitrarily large, function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring $h$ to be any function is not necessary. All you need is $h$ with support on arbitrary intervals, their size is irrelevant. I recommend you go over the proof of the lemma and convince yourself.

Comment: Interesting! Then why is the lemma often stated "..if the equality (the integral) is satisfied for *all* smooth functions $h(x)$ on the interval $a, b$.. "?

Comment: It is just a more elegant presentation but as you can check all you need is to be able to test against 'bumps' supported on arbitrarily small intervals.